# Placing white pixels on certain parts of an image (video) in kinect SDK

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, pixel, kinect

I am currently programming with Microsoft Kinect SDK. I am using the colour/video frame to display a video of me on the screen. Essentially I want to create a green (white) screen, where only the body of the user can be seen.

I have already gotten the area I need with the depth viewer, now I want to white out all the pixels in the video image that do not contain the user's body parts. I am trying to use the `SetPixel` function to accomplish this, however, I need a bitmap to apply it. Unfortunately by using a bitmap, I can't connect it with the "video" image. Here is my code:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(video);
myBitmap.SetPixel(row, column, System.Drawing.Color.White);
```

I get the following error message:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Drawing.Bitmap.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image)' has some invalid
>   arguments. Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Image'.

I believe this needs a string, such as a file name "video.png", but is it possible to take the xaml live-running "video" image instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code I've previously shared here: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Display-Kinect-color-image-containing-only-players-aka-background-removal